# Select specific levels of factor in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I imagine this is a relatively simple issue for this audience, at least it would be for me had I still been working with SAS...
I have a character factor (`"Trap"`) with 15 levels and I only want 3 of those levels (`Weka`, `Rat`, `Stoat`) for a data frame I want to summarize/analyze.  I don't want to use `droplevels` and have to write-out every level I DON'T want in the data frame, but I can't seem to get the coding right to select just the levels I want.  Please help.  Here's what I've most recently tried, to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CatchbySpecies <- CatchbySpecies [!CatchbySpecies$Trap == "Weka", "Rat", "Stoat"]
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to remove everything but these 3 levels? or you want to remove these 3 levels and keep everything else? or are you trying to split it into two data frames?

Comment: I'd like to create a new data frame and keep just the 3 levels that I specified.  Thanks.

Comment: So you want to use a different name on the left side of the `<-` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your text, it seems like you want to *keep* only those three levels -- if that's so, then you want:

```
CatchbySpecies <- CatchbySpecies [CatchbySpecies$Trap %in% c("Weka", "Rat", "Stoat"), ]
```

Key differences from your attempt:

1. No exclamation at the front, unless you want the *other* ones
2. Wrap the list of things you do want in the concatenate function, `c()`
3. Use `%in%` instead of `==`, since you don't want to check whether the factors are equal to the whole *vector* of `c("Weka", "Rat", "Stoat")`, but rather whether the factor is one of those elements contained within
4. Add a comma at the end. You're imposing a condition on the rows, so use a comma to indicate when that's done, and demonstrate an empty column condition.

Let me know if you have questions!

---

**EDIT**: You mentioned not wanting to use `droplevels()` and I wasn't quite sure why, but Ben Bolker helpfully pointed out that you may want to use it *after* doing this operation unless you want to retain the discarded factors in this variable for some reason. You can just edit the line as

```
CatchbySpecies <- 
  droplevels(CatchbySpecies [CatchbySpecies$Trap %in% c("Weka", "Rat", "Stoat"), ])
```

Comment: also: NSE-based approaches: `subset()` from base R and `dplyr::filter()` ... and don't forget `droplevels()` if desired

Comment: Thanks a bunch for everyone's help. I successfully used the first solution.  I was avoiding <- droplevels because I couldn't determine how to drop everything else BUT the 3 levels I wanted. My approach is the result of my lack of familiarity with R.  However, if you could write how I would code to implement droplevels, it would be very instructive! If not, I get that there are bigger fish to fry.

Comment: Edited to make it more clear how to use `droplevels()`. To further explain what it *does*: it throws away unused factor levels, which you will certainly have after this subsetting operation. (To see the difference it makes, try running `table(CatchbySpecies)` after the code in the first block of my post, and try running it again after the code in the second block of my post.)

Comment: Wouldn't the `droplevels()` call in your last solution also drop the `"Rat"` factor level if it just happened to not make an appearance in this set of data?

Comment: @Tom Sure - whether that's desirable is up to the OP, I suppose, but I generally like that.

Answer (score 1):

Should you want to explore `data.table`. This will reduce your code significantly

```
library(data.table)
CatchbySpecies <- CatchbySpecies[Trap %in% c("Weka", "Rat", "Stoat")]
```

You can subset your rows similar to a data.frame